# How can I align the .navigationBarTitle to the .toolbar next to it?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

[image: Navigation Bar]

I want to align the title to the toolbar item. How can I make it look a bit better. Thanks in advance.

```
.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .automatic)
.toolbar{
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
         Stepper("", value: $timeRemaining, in: 5...50, step: 5.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be looking for `displayMode: .inline`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, That is just not possible until today with Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e) in SwiftUI.